# Ionic 2 - Progressive Web App Only - How-to?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, progressive-web-apps

Since **I only need a Progressive Web App**; I was wondering if it's possible to not install Cordova as well as everything that is related to native apps when installating/setting up Ionic?

1. Do you think we could get rid of what is in bold? (see below after
   doing an ionic info command)
2. Do you have any thoughts / best
       practices to share?

The following components are part of Ionic or are needed

- **Cordova CLI: 6.5.0**
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
- **ios-deploy version: 1.9.0**
- **ios-sim version: 5.0.13**
- OS: OS X El Capitan Node Version: v7.0.0
- **Xcode version: Xcode
    8.2.1    Build    version 8C1002**

Comment: I'd be interested to hear some of the best practices for this. Thus far I have seen people recommend installing browser as a platform via `ionic platform add browser` and then building in prod mode with `ionic build browser --prod` for a small build bundle. But not 100% sure on deployment on conforming to PWA standards

Answer (score -2):

npm run ionic:build --prod

Just follow the instructions
https://www.gitbook.com/book/jgw96/ionic-pwa/details